# What does "Do agt for" mean in Georgia Property Tax Digests?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, property, georgia-usa

While reviewing the digital image of a record from the Ancestry.com collection, "Georgia, Property Tax Digests, 1793-1893," I found this phrase several times on the page:
"Do agt for" followed by a person name.

I'm not even sure that I'm transcribing it right, so I'm including a picture which shows 2 occurrences.[image]

I suspect there may be an abbreviation involved.  I suspect that understanding this entry may give a hint to the relationship between the names involved.

According to Ancestry.com, these records represent the "tax digest books for 135 Georgia counties from 1793 - 1893." For those with Ancestry.com access, you can see the entire page [here](http://search.ancestry.com/iexec?htx=View&r=an&dbid=1729&iid=40141_1020705384_0045-00037&fn=Anthony&ln=Edmonds&st=r&ssrc=gr_t44921181_p6278329995_ktidz0q3d44921181z0q26pidz0q3d6278329995z0q26hidz0q3d50517134994z0q26dbidz0q3d1729z0q26rpidz0q3d3501987z0q26hfz0q3dRecordz0q26pnz0q3d1z0q26hsz0q3drecentz0q26ssrcz0q3dgrz0q26pgz0q3d32880z0q26pgplz0q3dtidz0q257cpidz0q257chidz0q257cdbidz0q257crpidz0q257chfz0q257cpnz0q257chsz0q257cssrcz0q26pgpsz0q3d6278329995_h50517134994&pid=3501987)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search pertaining to the acronym agt yielded this fantastic snippet from ancestry.com. Hope this helps.: }

Agents

Agents, sometimes abbreviated Agt, represented the person who owed the tax. Women property holders often had men represent them on tax lists. The agent might be a family member, or he might represent a group who had sent one person to pay their taxes rather than all of them making the trip.

http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=1729

Answer (score 6):

I suspect "Do" represents "Ditto." See Wikipedia, "[Ditto Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark)," for the passage, "The abbreviation do. is also used."

I suspect also that "agt" represents "agent." See All-Acronyms.com for "[agt-agent](http://www.all-acronyms.com/AGT/agent/221019)."

I have not worked with the Georgia records before, but the names in the first column appear as obligors (to the tax) or payors. In this case, William Da __ sey appears obligated or to have paid taxes on his own account, but he also appears obligated or to have paid taxes as the agent for account of Sarah Da __ sey.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing; could `agt` be agent?

Comment: My apologies.  I meant to give the context but got distracted.  I have added the context as well as a link to the source on ancestry.com.

Comment: @womanamongmen All okay. I took the liberty of inserting a few more comments into the question. If this would not have been your intent, you can "edit" my edit and roll it back.

Comment: The edits are appropriate.  We'll all write better posts if we read better posts.

Comment: @womanamongmen It's a really good question; thanks for sharing.